# Is there an interpretation for why $\sigma(x) = x \iff x = 1$, that is not (purely) number-theoretic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum

The title says it all.

Let $\sigma = \sigma_{1}$ denote the classical sum-of-divisors function.  That is,
$$\sigma(N) = \sum_{d \mid N}{d}.$$
For example, $\sigma(10) = 1 + 2 + 5 + 10 = 18$.

Here is my question:

> Is there an interpretation for why $\sigma(x) = x \iff x = 1$, involving notions that can be extended outside elementary number theory?

**Things I Have In Mind**

> > **(1)** If $\sigma(x) = x$, then $$\gcd(x, \sigma(x)) = x = \sigma(x).$$
> >     How then do I show that $x=1$ (using only the concept of the greatest common divisor, (possibly) the definition of the $\sigma$ function, and no other)?
> >
> > **(2)** If $\sigma(x) = x$, then $x$ is said to be a *fixed point* of $\sigma$. Using concepts from functional analysis (and possibly, the definition of the $\sigma$ function), how do we then show that $x=1$?
> >
> > **(3)** If $\sigma(x) = x$, then since $\sigma$ *is* a function, we can apply $\sigma$ to both sides repeatedly to obtain
> >     $$x = \sigma(x) = \sigma(\sigma(x)) = \sigma(\sigma(\sigma(x))) = \sigma(\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(x)))) = \sigma(\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(x))))) = \ldots.$$
> >     This suggests a possible connection to recursion theory.  In particular, how do we then show that $x=1$, using only such a concept?

Comment: $x \mid x$ and $1 \mid x$ and thus $\sigma(x) \geq x + 1 > x$.

Comment: @menag, thank you for your comment.  I am already aware of that argument.  Indeed, that is one of the main proofs for the fact $\sigma(x) = x \implies x = 1$ *within elementary number theory*.  (The other direction, of course, is trivial.)  The point of my question was whether there are tools (i.e., concepts) outside elementary number theory that could prove the same statement.

Comment: $\sigma(n) > n$ when $n > 1$ that's just obvious. For problems of the kind $a | \sigma(n)$ or $\sigma(n) = a n$ you need to use that $\sigma(n) = \prod_{p^k | n} \sigma(p^k)$ i.e. that $\sigma(n)$ [is multiplicative](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/multiplicative-functions/)

Comment: Dumbest reason is that N|N so $\phi(N) = N + \sum_{d|N; d \ne N} d$ so $\phi(N) \iff \sum_{d|N d\ne N} = 0 \iff N$ has *no* divisors, not even 1, other than itself.

Comment: @user1952009, yes $\sigma$ is multiplicative (in fact, the appropriate term to use is *weakly multiplicative*, since $\sigma$ is multiplicative on *coprime* arguments only).  But how does that answer my questions, specifically **(1)**, **(2)**, and **(3)**?

Comment: The terminology is [multiplicative and completely multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function) (and $\ln \sigma(n)$ is additive, while $\ln n$ is completely additive), and sorry, you didn't ask any meaningful question.

Comment: @fleablood, I am unable to parse your two biconditionals.  Do you mean $\phi(N) = N$?

Comment: Its a typo, he meant $\sigma$ instead of $\phi$

Comment: Well, it's kind of silly.  for x > 1 then phi(x) >= x + 1 so if x is  fixed point of phi(x) then x > 1 means x = phi(x) >= x + 1 and ...

Comment: @user1952009, I'm asking fleablood, not you =)

Comment: @fleablood, just to be clear, $\phi(x)$ is the number of positive integers less than $x$ that are coprime to $x$, yes or no?

Comment: no, he meant $\sigma$, read what he wrote : $\sum_{d | n} d$

Comment: @fleablood, your last comment answers question **(2)**.  =)  I invite you to write it down as an actual response.

Comment: @user1952009, how do you then explain the terminology used in page 2, property #4 of this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1001v2.pdf) by Ward?

Comment: I'm just saying the *usual* termonology that is in every number theory book/course and that everyone understands on this forum is : multiplicative vs completely multiplicative

Comment: Agreed.  Read your comment again.  You were implying that the terminology *weakly multiplicative* does not exist in the literature.  =)

Comment: it does not exist in the literature I read.

Comment: What you read or do not read does not matter in my post.  And to say that a question is "not meaningful", without giving a *good answer* to why it is not, does not enlighten the OP.  =)

Comment: @ArnieBebitaDris meh... to be honest, I felt my comment was very vague.  It's not really an answer so much as an impression that the question can be soft-shoed tapped danced around.

Comment: And that was right.  phi (which usually means the number of divisors not the sum of the divisor) was the wrong symbol I mean .... rho?  or is it sigma?  Let's see  $\rho$ or $\sigma$.  ....? I meant $\sigma$ (not to be confused with $\Sigma$).

Comment: (1) I don't see why $\sigma$ would play nice with $\gcd$, unless you take into account $\sigma$'s multiplicativity and how to take $\gcd$s using factorizations. Also don't see why that wouldn't count as "pure number theory." (2)/(3) I have no idea why you think $\sigma$ is related to functional analysis or recursion theory. Bottom line: it's rather perplexing to see someone asking for deep explanations for such an obvious fact, and reaching for apparently unrelated mathematics to do so.

Comment: @arctictern: (1) Note that $1$ is [solitary](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SolitaryNumber.html), so that if $x=1$, then $\gcd(x,\sigma(x))=1$ by Greening's theorem.  My question is:  If only $\gcd(x,\sigma(x))=x$ or $\gcd(x,\sigma(x))=\sigma(x)$ is known, how do we derive $x=1$?  I agree that the phrasing of my questions are a bit vague, but I was thinking more along the lines of [UFDs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniqueFactorizationDomain.html) (and therefore, of abstract algebra and/or algebraic number theory, which would be *outside* elementary number theory). [continued]

Comment: @arctictern: Regarding (2)/(3), I am trying to understand why $1$ is the *only* fixed point of $\sigma$, and fleablood's earlier comment is a viable step in this direction.  I am also trying to understand why, when considering iterates of the $\sigma$ function, if you end up with the innermost argument of your nested $\sigma$'s, then necessarily you have that argument equal to one.

Comment: @fleablood, $\phi(N)$ is *not* the number of divisors of $N$.  I am guessing you meant $\tau(N)$ or $d(N)$ instead?  At any rate, your argument is valid.

Suppose that $x$ is a fixed point of $\sigma(x)$.  Then $\sigma(x)=x$.  We want to show that $x=1$.

Assume to the contrary that $x>1$.  Since $1 \mid x$ and $1< x \mid x$, we have $x = \sigma(x) \geq x+1$ (by the definition of the $\sigma$ function).  This is a contradiction.

Therefore, $x=1$.

**QED**

Comment: @Arnie Should I assume this is silliness for the sake of recreation? It reminds me of a funny joke answer to a very simple counting question that involved first establishing $-\frac{1}{12}$ was an integer using zeta regularization. Anyway, as for (2)/(3), $1$ is the only possible fixed point because it's the only time when $1$ and $x$ are not distinct summands in the definition of $\sigma(x)$, and all iterates only have $1$ as a fixed point because $\sigma(x)>x$ for $x>1$ implies $x,\sigma(x),\sigma^2(x),\cdots$ is monotonically increasing unless $x=1$. (Which I'm sure you're aware of.)

Comment: @arctictern, your comment qualifies as an actual answer, as it uses concepts that are "outside" *elementary number theory*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sigma(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} d \geq \sum_{d\mid n} 1 = d(n) \tag{1}$$
hence $\sigma(n)=1$ implies $d(n)=1$, but every natural number $n\geq 2$ has at least two distinct divisors, $1$ and $n$. Assuming $s>2$, from
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n^s} = \zeta(s)\,\zeta(s-1) \tag{2}$$
and summation by parts it follows that
$$ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sigma(n) = \frac{\pi^2 N}{6} + O(\sqrt{N})\tag{3} $$
hence $\sigma(n)=1$ may hold only for $n\in[1,N_0]$ for a fixed $N_0$, since $(3)$ gives $\sigma(N)=\frac{\pi^2}{3}N+O(\sqrt{N})$, on average.

Comment: Thanks Jack!  Your response draws from results in analytic number theory, so it qualifies as an acceptable answer to my original questions.

Answer (score 3):

Things are much more simple than that!

First of all, the $\Leftarrow$ way is obvious.

To prove the other way you just have to observe that if $x>1$ then $1|x$ and $x|x$ and $x\neq 1$ so $σ(x)\geq x+1\Rightarrow σ(x)>x$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Please see my other comment below menag's.

Comment: OK. Missed that!